# How to add ngIf Condition

Tags: ionic2

I need to show the image, if the condition is true on ionic2 page (.html)
With reference to angular documentation I am trying the following:
Here is the reference [angular doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)
Inside the for loop, leg is accessible if I try to print it within div tag. But, it is not accessible in condition.

```
<div *ngIf="{{leg.legIndex}} == 0" >
  <!-- show image middleLeg_1.png if legIndex = 0 -->
<img width="20" height="80" src="img/middleLeg_1.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
The condition should not have the curly brackets. Before, in the condition, I was accessing variable with curly brackets as we do in ionic2 tags. But, in `ngif`, it's not needed. We can access our variables within for loop, without it.
Here is the correct answer:

```
<div *ngIf="leg.legIndex == 0" >
  <!-- show image middleLeg_1.png if legIndex = 0 -->
<img width="20" height="80" src="img/middleLeg_1.png" />
</div>
```